# Apache with passenger gives error(Premature end of script headers) in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm using Apache + passenger for my rails application, The application is running fine in production mode except when the browser displays error message after every 2-3 clicks in development mode which goes off when i refresh the page.I'm using metal in my rails application which i see could be the reason but not sure if it is the only reason.

**Error message on browser**:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

**Apache log Error:**

```
[Thu Dec 01 16:55:23 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: view_transactions, referer: http://localhost/admin_portal/1014978061/view_transactions
[ pid=660 thr=3078097552 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:822 time=2011-12-01 16:55:23.563 ]: The backend application (process 796) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
[ pid=796 thr=-608495398 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-12-01 11:25:23.878 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in application (undefined method `new' for Rails:Module) (process 796, thread #<Thread:0xb77631b4>):
from /home/brijendra/aptana_studio_3_workspace/wantsa/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/control.rb:467:in `new_instance'
from /home/brijendra/aptana_studio_3_workspace/wantsa/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/control.rb:54:in `instance'
from /home/brijendra/aptana_studio_3_workspace/wantsa/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:167:in `logger'
```

I would be eager to post any other output if required and also suggestions to fix this issue.

Comment: What are your Ruby, Rails and NewRelic versions? There might be an incompatibility amongst these.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], Rails 2.3.4, newrelic v2.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by changing cache as true in my development.rb and it worked fine.